# is_object() handled by Exceptions?

Tags: php, oop, object, exception

I researched for a way to check if an object is an object (not a particular instance of a class) and i found `is_object();`.
Does `is_object()` throw any exceptions? Is there a way to throw an exceptions with this language construct?

```
private function objectInjector($object) {
    try {
        is_object($object);
        return strtolower(get_class($object));
    } catch (Exception $ex) { 
        $this->ex = $ex->getMessage();
        if (APP_DEBUG) {
            d($ex->getTrace());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function **is_object()** returns a bool and should be used in an if statement in order to correctly handle the result.

You can find more on the PHP documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-object.php

There is a why you need to throw an exception in that function?
If not you can just add this code in your logic without delegate to objectInjector:

```
if (is_object($object)) {
    //do stuff with your object
} else {
   //do anything else, is not an object
}
```

The you can use a try/catch statement on top of your function/method to handle any other expection.

Bye!

Comment: Thank you. I was searching for a way to handle exceptions with this. The method is used in a class as a private method. I will go for a return error message.